# xoring two binary string list

Tags: python, binary

```
a=['0011001100',0100011011',
 '0110111001', '1001001010',
 '1010001000', '1001000001',
 '0101001111', '1110010001',
 '0011101111', '0101010100',
 '0010110000', '1011110111',
 '0000011101', '0000011100']
d=['0101001111', '1110010001',
 '0011101111', '0101010100',
 '0010110000', '1011110111',
 '0000011101', '0000011100',
 '1011110000', '0010010111',
 '0100010010', '0001100101',
 '1010010101', '1110101101']
c=a^d
```

**trying to do xor  operation between these to data set. any help**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to xor corresponding elements from `a` and `d`, and both inputs and outputs are supposed to be as strings, you can do this:

```
c = [bin(int(A, 2) ^ int(D, 2))[2:] for A, D in zip(a, d)]
#  ['110000011', '1010001010', 
#   '101010110', '1100011110', 
#   '1000111000', '10110110', 
#   '101010010', '1110001101', 
#   '1000011111', '111000011', 
#   '110100010', '1010010010', 
#   '1010001000', '1110110001']
```

Converts both `A` (from `a`) and `D` (from `d`) to integers, performs bitwise `xor`, then converts them back into a binary string using `bin()`, and finally chops off the preceding `'0b'` with a simple slice.

If you want them all to be the same length (the 10 characters you started with), you can take that resulting string, and right-justify it, filling the unused space with leading zeroes:

```
c = [bin(int(A, 2) ^ int(D, 2))[2:].rjust(10, '0') for A, D in zip(a, d)]
#  ['0110000011', '1010001010', 
#   '0101010110', '1100011110', 
#   '1000111000', '0010110110', 
#   '0101010010', '1110001101', 
#   '1000011111', '0111000011', 
#   '0110100010', '1010010010', 
#   '1010001000', '1110110001']
```

Comment: one more help . plz let me know how m i going to convert these new c values in decimal ?

Comment: If you want them in decimal, you can just leave out the `bin()` call. By default, the output of the `xor` operation will output an integer. So to get the integer results of `xor`ing corresponding elements from `a` and `d` you would just do `c = [int(A, 2) ^ int(D, 2) for A, D in zip(a, d)]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def XOR_func(a, d):
    c = []
    for i in len(a):
        a_list = list(a[i])
        d_list = list(d[i])
        c_list = []
        for j in len(a_list):
           if a_list[j] == "0" and d_list[j] == "0":
                 c_list.append("0")
           if a_list[j] == "0" and d_list[j] == "1":
                 c_list.append("1")
           if a_list[j] == "1" and d_list[j] == "0":
                 c_list.append("1")
           if a_list[j] == "1" and d_list[j] == "1":
                 c_list.append("0")
       c.append(''.join(c_list))
    return c
```